# Initialize static string (either C-type or std::string) with respect to Google C++ Style Guide

Tags: c++, static, stdstring

As per [Google C++ Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html), section "Static and Global Variables" claims that: "As a result we only allow static variables to contain POD data. This rule completely disallows `std::vector` (use C arrays instead), or `string` (use `const char []`)." Suppose that my program need some static strings that are stored in a configuration file and will be loaded at runtime. Then how would it be possible to load strings into a `const char[]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignoring the merits of Google's C++ style guide, you would presumably store it in a `const char*` variable which gets its pointer via dynamic allocation:

```
static const char *my_static_string = nullptr;

...

void load_static_string()
{
  if(!my_static_string)
  {
    std::string str = //Read string from file.
    my_static_string = new char[str.size() + 1];
    strncpy(my_static_string, str.data(), str.size() + 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Exactly (and good example). They have something similar in the last sentence of that section: "If you need a static or global variable of a class type, consider initializing a pointer (which will never be freed), from either your main() function or from pthread_once(). Note that this must be a raw pointer, not a "smart" pointer, since the smart pointer's destructor will have the order-of-destructor issue that we are trying to avoid."

Answer (score 0):

You will have to specify the length of the string at compile time. You will need to know the maximum length that a string can be before execution.

Given the length:

```
const std::size_t len = 2048;   // can store 2047 characters with null-terminating '\0'
```

You can do this in c style

```
char buffer[len];
```

Or better yet, use `std::array`

```
#include <array>
std::array<char,len> buffer;
```

Then open your file into an ifstream, and parse the data appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you have a string stored in a configuration file has **NOTHING** to do on how you're going to load it. You can load the data to `const char[]` or to an `std::string` or anything else, depending on what's convenient for you at your specific case.

The rule is just about not allowing non-POD global/static variables... that's it.